# Losing initial log events using log4j2 socket appender when destination disconnects tcp connection after idle time out

Tags: java, sockets, logging, log4j2, tcp

We are facing intermittent lost of logs while sending logs to log target using log4j2 socket appender in our application. The detailed information is as below;

Our environment:

1. In our application, we are using log4j2 (2.7 version jar) framework and SocketAppender (async appender under socket appender) to send logs to Splunk (Enterprise Logging tool) via radware(load balancer).
2. So our application connects to Radware over TCPIP socket using SocketAppender; Radware is used to load balance load among 4 target Splunk servers.
3. Radware Server is configured to timeout if connection is idle for one minute (configurable at radware and set to 1 minute)
4. The configuration of log4j2 config file is as below:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration status="trace" monitorInterval="5">
       <Appenders>
           <Socket name="socket" host="10.52.214.26" port="1514" reconnectDelayMillis="30000" immediateFail="false" bufferedIo="true" bufferSize="204800" protocol="TCP" immediateFlush="false">
               <PatternLayout></PatternLayout>
           </Socket>
           <Async name="SplunkAsync" bufferSize="204800">
               <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
           </Async>
       </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
       <Root level="warn">
           <AppenderRef ref="SplunkAsync"/>
       </Root>
       <Logger name="SplunkInfoLogger" level="info" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="SplunkAsync"/>
       </Logger>
       <Logger name="SplunkDebugLogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="SplunkAsync"/>
       </Logger>
       <Logger name="SplunkWarnLogger" level="warn" additivity="false">
           <AppenderRef ref="SplunkAsync"/>
       </Logger>
   </Loggers>
   ```

The process/steps of meeting problem:

1. Splunk servers, radware server and our application servers are up, and the application servers send logs to radware in turn splunk servers successfully.
2. As we didn't do any operation, there is no logs come into radware in one minute ( 1 minute as we set) and radware breaks the connection between it and application server.
3. We did an operation so that application server will write one log. However nothing happens, This log didn't come into radware and splunk servers at all.
4. We did a second operation so that application server will write the second log. This time also logs did not  come into radware and splunk either.
5. After counting for 30 sec (`reconnectDelayMillis="30000"` in log4j2 config file) from first failed log (i.e the log triggered after radware breaks connection) we did a third operation so that application server will write the third log. This time SocketAppender works well and this log came into radware and splunk servers. This is primarily because application server is able to re-establish connection to Radware after 30 sec as `reconnectDelayMillis="30000"`

I would like to know why initial logs are lost which are sent after radware connection becomes idle. Ideally, tcp connection created by log4j2 should keep the data in buffer when connection is broken and should send data from buffer when reconnection is established after 30 secs (reconnectDelayMillis="30000" )

We tried setting up parameters like immediateFail="false" bufferedIo="true" bufferSize="204800", so that data can be stored in buffer when radware times out tcp connection and can be sent later when reconnection to radware is established, Unfortunately which is not happening.

Are we missing any configurations because which we are facing this type of behaviour or is it known defect.

The similar kind of issue is also observed by others and raised in apache jira( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1311 )

```
-------------------
Console Log
---------------------
Configuration(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml), connectTimeoutMillis="null", host="10.52.214.26", immediateFail="false", port="1514", protocol="TCP", reconnectDelayMillis="30000", SslConfiguration=null, bufferedIo="true", bufferSize="204800", immediateFlush="false", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%m%n), name="socket", Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.053     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,052 Thread-39 DEBUG Starting TcpSocketManager TCP:10.52.214.26:1514
2017-05-15 17:27:15.054     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,054 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.066     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,066 Thread-39 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="socket", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.070     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,070 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.081     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,081 Thread-39 DEBUG AsyncAppender$Builder(={socket}, errorRef="null", blocking="null", shutdownTimeout="null", bufferSize="204800", name="SplunkAsync", includeLocation="null", Filter=null, Configuration(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml), ignoreExceptions="null", BlockingQueueFactory=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.084     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,083 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.086     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,085 Thread-39 DEBUG createAppenders(={socket, SplunkAsync})
2017-05-15 17:27:15.087     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,087 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.089     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,089 Thread-39 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="SplunkAsync", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.091     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,090 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.094     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,094 Thread-39 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="WARN", includeLocation="null", ={SplunkAsync}, ={}, Configuration(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.115     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,113 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.120     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,120 Thread-39 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="SplunkAsync", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.123     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,123 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.128     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,127 Thread-39 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="INFO", name="SplunkInfoLogger", includeLocation="null", ={SplunkAsync}, ={}, Configuration(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.130     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,130 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.133     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,132 Thread-39 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="SplunkAsync", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.134     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,134 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.147     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,146 Thread-39 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="DEBUG", name="SplunkDebugLogger", includeLocation="null", ={SplunkAsync}, ={}, Configuration(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.148     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,148 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=AppenderRef, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.151     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,150 Thread-39 DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="SplunkAsync", level="null", Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.152     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,152 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.156     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,156 Thread-39 DEBUG createLogger(additivity="false", level="WARN", name="SplunkWarnLogger", includeLocation="null", ={SplunkAsync}, ={}, Configuration(C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-05-15 17:27:15.158     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,157 Thread-39 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2017-05-15 17:27:15.165     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,165 Thread-39 DEBUG createLoggers(={root, SplunkInfoLogger, SplunkDebugLogger, SplunkWarnLogger})
2017-05-15 17:27:15.167     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,167 Thread-39 DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml] initialized
2017-05-15 17:27:15.169     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,168 Thread-39 DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml]
2017-05-15 17:27:15.178     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,178 Thread-39 DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml] OK.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.180     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,180 Thread-39 TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@ce510e6c...
2017-05-15 17:27:15.181     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,181 Thread-39 TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.184     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,184 Thread-39 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.185     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,185 Thread-39 TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.187     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,186 Thread-39 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.188     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,187 Thread-39 DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2017-05-15 17:27:15.189     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,189 Thread-39 DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2017-05-15 17:27:15.190     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,190 Thread-39 TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.191     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,191 Thread-39 TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.193     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,193 Thread-39 DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@ce510e6c OK
2017-05-15 17:27:15.198     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,197 Thread-39 TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@7a7e9cb6
2017-05-15 17:27:15.199     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,199 Thread-39 TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): 'c1edad85' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@c1b7efc0
2017-05-15 17:27:15.200     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,200 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.202     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,202 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=StatusLogger'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.203     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,203 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=ContextSelector'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.205     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,205 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Loggers,name=*'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.213     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,213 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Appenders,name=*'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.215     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,214 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.216     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,216 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.218     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,217 Thread-39 TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2017-05-15 17:27:15.220     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,220 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85
2017-05-15 17:27:15.225     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,225 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=StatusLogger
2017-05-15 17:27:15.234     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,234 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=ContextSelector
2017-05-15 17:27:15.238     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,237 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Loggers,name=SplunkWarnLogger
2017-05-15 17:27:15.240     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,240 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Loggers,name=
2017-05-15 17:27:15.242     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,242 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Loggers,name=SplunkDebugLogger
2017-05-15 17:27:15.243     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,243 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Loggers,name=SplunkInfoLogger
2017-05-15 17:27:15.246     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,246 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=Appenders,name=socket
2017-05-15 17:27:15.249     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,249 Thread-39 DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=c1edad85,component=AsyncAppenders,name=SplunkAsync
2017-05-15 17:27:15.253     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,253 Thread-39 TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.255     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,254 Thread-39 TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.256     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,256 Thread-39 DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=c1edad85] at URI C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQSI\common\wsrr\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@c1b7efc0) with optional ClassLoader: null
2017-05-15 17:27:15.257     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,257 Thread-39 DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2017-05-15 17:27:15.259     53 2017-05-15 17:27:15,259 Thread-39 DEBUG LoggerContext[name=c1edad85, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@c1b7efc0] started OK.
2017-05-15 17:27:20.568     49 [15/5/17 17:27:20:558 IST] 00000031 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0018I: The trace state has changed. The new trace state is *=info.
2017-05-15 17:29:02.135     56 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory).
2017-05-15 17:29:02.136     56 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
2017-05-15 17:29:02.136     56 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
2017-05-15 17:29:07,135 AsyncAppender-SplunkAsync ERROR Unable to write to stream TCP:10.52.214.26:1514 for appender socket: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:10.52.214.26:1514
2017-05-15 17:29:07.137     60 2017-05-15 17:29:07,136 AsyncAppender-SplunkAsync ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender socket org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:10.52.214.26:1514
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.writeByteArrayToManager(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:185)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.directEncodeEvent(SocketAppender.java:424)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:169)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:160)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.callAppenders(AsyncAppender.java:451)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:404)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:125)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:133)
    ... 11 more
2017-05-15 17:29:07.361     60 2017-05-15 17:29:07,360 AsyncAppender-SplunkAsync ERROR Unable to write to stream TCP:10.52.214.26:1514 for appender socket: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:10.52.214.26:1514
2017-05-15 17:29:07.363     60 2017-05-15 17:29:07,361 AsyncAppender-SplunkAsync ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender socket org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:10.52.214.26:1514
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:197)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.writeByteArrayToManager(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:185)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.directEncodeEvent(SocketAppender.java:424)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:169)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:160)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.callAppenders(AsyncAppender.java:451)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AsyncAppender$AsyncThread.run(AsyncAppender.java:404)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:125)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:171)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:133)
    ... 11 more
2017-05-15 17:29:41.801    247 2017-05-15 17:29:41,801 Log4j2-TcpSocketManager-Reconnector DEBUG Connection to 10.52.214.26:1514 reestablished.
2017-05-15 17:31:37.844    261 2017-05-15 17:31:37,844 Log4j2-TcpSocketManager-Reconnector DEBUG Connection to 10.52.214.26:1514 reestablished.
2017-05-15 17:36:40.838     60 2017-05-15 17:36:40,837 AsyncAppender-SplunkAsync ERROR Unable to write to stream TCP:10.52.214.26:1514 for appender socket: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TCP:10.52.214.26:1514
2017-05-15 17:37:10.987    293 2017-05-15 17:37:10,986 Log4j2-TcpSocketManager-Reconnector DEBUG Connection to 10.52.214.26:1514 reestablished.
```

Comment: Can anyone faced similar kind of issue ? Any probable solution